# How do I reference an SSL cert from within Azure

Tags: azure, ssl

I've uploaded a SSL cert to Azure for use in a mutual auth call to a SOAP service.  However I simply cannot find it in any store or location.

```
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="F1F12265ABCDE9E23941234583E2668B09876B2"
             storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="CertificateAuthority"
             x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </clientCredentials>
```

I've tried a number of different stores but repeated get the same error:

```
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindByThumbprint',
FindValue 'F1F12265ABCDE9E23941234583E2668B09876B2'.
```

Can anyone help?  I've been stuck on this now for a few hours trying different combinations and googling.  Seems it simply cannot see it.

Comment: 'My' on 'LocalMachine' sounds about right. The certificate has been correctly uploaded through the portal and is present in the csdef/cscfg? Have you tried remoting to the machine to check if it is actually present?

Comment: Could it be because you're instructing Windows Azure to install it in `CertificateAuthority` store and searching for it in `My` store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468244/simon-opelt), I'm not sure why I cannot comment on your comment, but thank you.  Indeed I had added a certificate into the csdef when I was adding https to our own service (which we no longer needed) and had inadvertently deleted the reference to the certificate to be used for mutual auth.